# Using await SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync in .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, semaphore, async-await

My application is using .NET 4. I am using await async using [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/)

In my application I want to do an await on sempahore WaitAsync call as follows.

```
SemaphoreSlim semphore = new SemaphoreSlim(100);
await semphore.WaitAsync();
```

However I am getting following compilation error.

> > 'System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim' does not contain a definition for 'WaitAsync' and no extension method 'WaitAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Could there be anyway of uisng WaitAsync in .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` in .Net 4.0 since this method was added to [`SemaphoreSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.100).aspx) in .Net 4.5.

You can however implement your own `AsyncSemaphore` following Stephen Toub's example in [Building Async Coordination Primitives, Part 5: AsyncSemaphore](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-5-asyncsemaphore/):

```
public class AsyncSemaphore
{
    private readonly static Task s_completed = Task.FromResult(true);
    private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> m_waiters = new Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();
    private int m_currentCount; 

    public AsyncSemaphore(int initialCount)
    {
        if (initialCount < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("initialCount");
        m_currentCount = initialCount;
    }

    public Task WaitAsync()
    {
        lock (m_waiters)
        {
            if (m_currentCount > 0)
            {
                --m_currentCount;
                return s_completed;
            }
            else
            {
                var waiter = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                m_waiters.Enqueue(waiter);
                return waiter.Task;
            }
        }
    }
    public void Release()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> toRelease = null;
        lock (m_waiters)
        {
            if (m_waiters.Count > 0)
                toRelease = m_waiters.Dequeue();
            else
                ++m_currentCount;
        }
        if (toRelease != null)
            toRelease.SetResult(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile with Framework 4.0 because Task.FromResult is not defined. I have replaced Task.FromResult(true) with new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(true).Task. This compiles but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: My simple change did not work. I have made a different change and posted the code as a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, .NET 4.5 introduced `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync`.

For .NET 4.0, you can either [write your own async-compatible lock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx) or [use one](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock) from my [Nito.AsyncEx NuGet package](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx).

Comment: you first link is dead and the seconf one pointing to GitHub AsyncEx doesn't support anymore .Net 4.0.

Comment: @sodjsn26fr: Microsoft changed the first link, and if you still need .NET 4.0 in 2020, you'll need to use an old version of Nito.AsyncEx which is still available on NuGet.

Comment: @Phil Jollans, thank you. But I tried "Phil Jollans" answer with success. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

`WaitAsync` is introduced with .Net 4.5. You either need to implement yourself as an extension method by looking into [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/SemaphoreSlim.cs,7a679e542c73988f)(not sure if that is possible), or you can use StephenToub's [AsyncSemaphore](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266983.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll need to upgrade to .NET 4.5 (or write a `WaitAsync` extension (or inherently asynchronous semaphore) yourself).

The async extensions for .NET 4.0 are there to allow for the support of the actual `await` keyword.  Much of the work of .NET 4.5 is adding asynchronous operations to various BCL types that can be awaited.  If you need those operations, you'll need to upgrade the version of the framework you use.

Answer (score 1):

As the `WaitAsync` isn't avaliable in .NET 4.0, You can use the code from [Stephan Toub's series of async synchronization primitives](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266983.aspx):

```
public class AsyncSemaphore 
{ 
    private readonly static Task s_completed = Task.FromResult(true); 
    private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> m_waiters = 
                                            new Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>(); 
    private int m_currentCount; 

    public AsyncSemaphore(int initialCount)
    {
        if (initialCount < 0) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("initialCount"); 
        }
        m_currentCount = initialCount; 
    }

    public Task WaitAsync() 
    { 
        lock (m_waiters) 
        { 
            if (m_currentCount > 0) 
            { 
                --m_currentCount; 
                return s_completed; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                var waiter = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(); 
                m_waiters.Enqueue(waiter); 
                return waiter.Task; 
            } 
        } 
    }

    public void Release() 
    { 
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> toRelease = null; 
        lock (m_waiters) 
        { 
            if (m_waiters.Count > 0) 
                toRelease = m_waiters.Dequeue(); 
            else 
                ++m_currentCount; 
        } 
        if (toRelease != null) 
            toRelease.SetResult(true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Link is now broken 403

Answer (score 1):

The class AysncSemaphore, posted in two other answers, does not compile with Framework 4.0, because Task.FromResult is not defined.

This is my alternative version:

```
public class AsyncSemaphore
{
    private readonly static Task s_completed ;
    private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> m_waiters = new Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();
    private int m_currentCount; 

    static AsyncSemaphore()
    {
      var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
      tcs.SetResult(true);
      s_completed = tcs.Task ;
    }

    public AsyncSemaphore(int initialCount)
    {
        if (initialCount < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("initialCount");
        m_currentCount = initialCount;
    }

    public Task WaitAsync()
    {
        lock (m_waiters)
        {
            if (m_currentCount > 0)
            {
                --m_currentCount;
                return s_completed;
            }
            else
            {
                var waiter = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                m_waiters.Enqueue(waiter);
                return waiter.Task;
            }
        }
    }
    public void Release()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> toRelease = null;
        lock (m_waiters)
        {
            if (m_waiters.Count > 0)
                toRelease = m_waiters.Dequeue();
            else
                ++m_currentCount;
        }
        if (toRelease != null)
            toRelease.SetResult(true);
    }
}
```